# Binding Native C library in Xamarin project

Tags: c, xamarin

I am currently have an issue of binding c library. I am following the introduction from this link to bind C library in Xamarin project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUoPLcmnf1o (It is a Xamarin Unversity Turtorial regarding binding c/c++ library, I literally did the same thing except those caused by environment differences ). However, I am stuck at the last step: using functions from the c library in the Xamarin project, it always shows "Native linking failed, undefined symbol *". I have tried to solve it for around 2 days, but did not go any further, may I ask for your help? Thank you very much in advance.

Environment: iOS: macOS High Sierra, xcode: 10.1, SDK: 12.1, IDE: Visual Studio for Mac

Does anyone has followed the same tutorial before and know how to do it? I am totally stuck on this. Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Can you pastebin the entire build log?

Comment: I suggest going over this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/native-interop#accessing-c-methods-from-c . Make sure you set the linker flags in the

Comment: I am trying to use C binary in Xamarin Forms UWP but I am unable to find any resource.  @jgoldberger-MSFT any idea how to do that?

Comment: @pixel - calling in to a C library from C# is the same no matter the calling platform, IOW you have to use the P/Invoke mechanism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT I read that article,that is great but I am still not sure how to use that static C lib binary? I guess I just need to add it to my UWP project (right-click > add existing item) and then in my lib properties, choose BuildAction=Content? After that I should be able to define DllImports for the methods advertised in the header .h file for the 3rd party library?

Comment: I might have to take back what I said before. I see no way to add a C static library to a C# UWP app. You may have to use a C++ UWP project to consume a static C library, but that won't work with Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT Yes, that is exactly the feeling I am having.  I believe you can only use a .NET dll library in a Xamarin UWP project.  Btw, and unrelated to this question, your post "Getting Started with Async / Await" saved my a.., I'd like to thank you on that. Thumbs UP!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped.

Comment: @chygo Have you been able to figure out this?  I started looking as I got a C lib from 3rd party client to use in Xamarin.forms UWP but then it turned out they also have a .Net dll lib which I ended up using instead but still interested to learn.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [overview of the approach](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/using-c-libraries-xamarin-forms-apps/) which also refers to this step-by-step guide will give an idea of how to [prepare the binding for c/cpp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/). The is also a video with a [quick demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48CC0_Jc3_I).